# Configuring Custom 404 Page in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have to configure the 404 page using the `web.config` file.
I designed a custom 404 page and place it in the root directory.

Here is my code:

```
    <httpErrors>
           <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
           <error statusCode="404" path="http://example.net/404Page.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> //here is my code to redirect the user to the 404 page
    </httpErrors>
```

But it not works for me.

Comment: `But it not works for me.` Okay, so that means that you're reaching a page you weren't expecting to instead, right? What page is that? Is there a different error message related to your web.config on that page? Help us out here.

Comment: suppose a user comes to my site http://example.net/abcadsffd
which dosn't exist.so i have to redirect the user  to 404 page.but it always shows me the text  "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." instead of that 404Page.php that i made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what you get

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://example.net/404Page.php" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I tried this code but got this error.and the site stops working.

Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: A couple of questions, First where is this site deployed ? i.e. IIS7/8, or are you trying to run from VS and which Framework version are you using?